# Facebook webhook notifications not being sent

Tags: facebook, webhooks

I've set up a webhook (following the instructions from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) for comments posted to my website.

The App is set to live, I've set the comments and comments replies to be subscribed to and the tests run all work fine but when comments are posted on the site the webhook doesn't appear to trigger.

Has anyone else had this issue or can they point me in the right direction please? I'd asked on the Facebook Developer's Community but haven't had a response yet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your app in live or in dev mode?

Comment: How did you determine that it does not trigger, or does not “appear” to do so? What does your server access log say, any incomming requests for this, or none at all?

Comment: It's in live mode, the webhook for it to hit sends an email regardles of input (which gets sent through the Facebook test) but this isn't being sent when a new comment/reply is added to a post

Comment: Is the page you are commenting on correctly connected to your app id via a `fb:app_id` meta tag?

Comment: Yes that's correct, it's got

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="3255202684603103" />

in the header

Comment: Did you have that previously already, or did you add it only recently? If the latter, use the FB debug tool to refresh their cache of your URL(s)’ meta data.

Comment: It's been in place since the app was created last week - if I need to refresh the cache what is the URL for the Facebook debugger please? I can only see the sharer debugger which says one of the links hasn't been shared (for example https://www.patricktomlinson.com/create-your-organization-s-unique-therapeutic-model-for-traumatized-children-young-people/61)

Comment: Yes, that one. You need to scrape your URL at least once (would happen automatically, if someone _shared_ the URL on Facebook), for Facebook to read the OG meta data.

Comment: Ok great, that's been done and it's showing the APP ID successfully when showing the debug results of the page. Does anything else need to be done for that one URL (there are others but I can scrape them) for it to work for the webhook notifications?

Comment: I don’t see any further requirements mentioned in the documentation. (The URL you are commenting _on_ is different than the one you embedded the plugin on though, for the example URL you have given. But as long as the URL you are commenting on has the correct app id set, that should not matter.)

Comment: Still no luck with when adding a comment or reply - this is strange. Anything else you can suggest to try please? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Nah, never used webhooks for comments plugin myself before. Try and ask in the Facebook Developers Group on FB maybe.